# Android Jitpack Private Repo Authorisation

Tags: android, github, jitpack

I am trying to add a library hosted on private repo through JitPack.
I authorised JitPack with my Github account which is under my company(organisation) as following and it is working fine.

1. Add the token to $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
authToken=AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN
```

2. Use authToken as the username in your build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
     repositories {
         ...
         maven {
             url "https://jitpack.io"
             credentials { username authToken }
         }
     }  
}
```

Now I have done implementation and want to push this feature to organisation's remote repo. And ***I don't want this authorisation to depend on my personal token, I want to authorise as an organisation. Does anyone know how can I do that?***

Because I found two statements [here](https://docs.jitpack.io/private/): it's said we can subscribe JitPack either as user or an organisation, and another statement said that every team member should get their own token. So, I am wondering how can I do it as an organisation rather than as a user.

> A JitPack Subscription is tied to a specific GitHub/Bitbucket account which can be either **a user or an organization**.

and this

> Each member of your team should to get their own token.

*P.S: I know that if we want to host our private repo on JitPack, we can authorise JitPack at an organisation level by using OAuth. But I don't know how can I do if I want to access some other private repo on JitPack as an organisation.*

Comment: Found any solution @kara?

Comment: Sadly not found yet and we stopped the implementation for now.